# Angular 6 and operators

Tags: angular

I have a simple ts component and I have a problem. I updated project to angular 6 and i get error with rxjs operators. When I'm try to run this code from component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, resolve, pipe } from 'rxjs';
import { map, take } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { interval } from 'rxjs/observable/interval';
...
observableData: number;
subscription: Object = null;

constructor() {
    this.subscribeObservable();
}

getObservable() { 
return Observable
    .interval(1000)
    .take(10)
    .map((v) => v * v);
}

subscribeObservable() { 
this.subscription = this.getObservable()
    .subscribe( v => this.observableData = v);
}

ngOnDestroy() { 
    if (this.subscription) {
      this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

I get the fllowing errors:

> ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(2,22): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Workspace/bitbucket/async-pipe-with-promises-and-observable/node_modules/rxjs/index"' has no exported member 'resolve'.
>   src/app/app.component.ts(25,10): error TS2339: Property 'interval' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'.
>   src/app/app.component.ts(37,25): error TS2339: Property 'unsubscribe' does not exist on type 'Object'.

Does anybody know how to fix it?

Edit:

When i try :

```
import { Observable, resolve, pipe, interval, map, take } from 'rxjs';
```

I get errors:

> ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(2,22): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Workspace/bitbucket/async-pipe-with-promises-and-observable/node_modules/rxjs/index"' has no exported member 'resolve'.
>   src/app/app.component.ts(2,47): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Workspace/bitbucket/async-pipe-with-promises-and-observable/node_modules/rxjs/index"' has no exported member 'map'.
>   src/app/app.component.ts(2,52): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Workspace/bitbucket/async-pipe-with-promises-and-observable/node_modules/rxjs/index"' has no exported member 'take'.
>   src/app/app.component.ts(25,10): error TS2339: Property 'interval' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'.
>   src/app/app.component.ts(37,25): error TS2339: Property 'unsubscribe' does not exist on type 'Object'.

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "async-pipe-with-promises-and-observable",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "^6.1.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.5",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.5",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~1.4.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subscription, interval, pipe } from 'rxjs';
import { map, take } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Replace `subscription: Object = null;` by `subscription: Subscription = null;`

and replace

```
return Observable
    .interval(1000)
    .take(10)
    .map((v) => v * v);
```

by

```
return interval(1000).pipe(
   take(10),
   map((v) => v * v)
);
```

Comment: I get:
ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(24,10): error TS2339: Property 'interval' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'.

Comment: yes, because your line `Observable
    .interval` is wrong. Replace by `return
    interval(1000).pipe(
     take(10),
    map((v) => v * v));`

Answer (score -1):

operators should now all be under:

```
from "rxjs"
```

since angular 6 uses rxjs 6

Comment: I would try to delete your node_modules and reinstall. it might be that it's trying to use your old modules

Comment: it is sad, but nothing happened